# Javascript event on XPage ViewColumnHeader Sort

Tags: sorting, view, xpages, lotus

I'm working with XPages recently and I'm having trouble with the sorting of data in container controls. I've been able to get data to display well through multiple solutions, view panels, data tables, and repeat controls, but sorting seems to only work well through view panels. (After doing some research and realizing that Java.Util.TreeMap provides some utility for other containers). However, the problem I'm having is that the images that view column headers add for sorting aren't what I want.

So, my question is this:
Is there any way to either change where XPages looks for those images (Knowing I can set a class on that image tag through Image.ViewColumnHeaderSort doesn't help due to not having access to the event) or can I access the event in order to set a scoped variable that I could use to compute a class on my TH elements.

Thanks in advance,
Aaron Brake
4CTechnologies

Comment: Consider using DynamicView control with customizer bean.

Comment: I had the view working in a DynamicView at one point but I don't know what you mean by "Customizer Bean". Can you elaborate?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://github.com/jesse-gallagher/Domino-One-Offs/tree/master/mcl/reports You can put this class inside your NSF and put in Customizer bean property of Dynamic view control to modify rendering of it.

Comment: Another good read http://www.slideshare.net/perlausten/xpages-extension-library-create-an-app-in-1-hour-almost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a workaround for this problem, it uses the URL parameter for sorting the view panel columns.

Example XPage:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:this.resources>
        <xp:script src="/jssViewSort.jss" clientSide="false"></xp:script>
    </xp:this.resources>

    <xp:viewPanel rows="30" id="viewPanel2">
        <xp:this.facets>
            <xp:pager partialRefresh="true" layout="Previous Group Next"
                xp:key="headerPager" id="pager2">
            </xp:pager>
        </xp:this.facets>
        <xp:this.data>
            <xp:dominoView var="view1" viewName="_YOUR_VIEW_"></xp:dominoView>
        </xp:this.data>
        <xp:viewColumn columnName="Form" id="viewColumn3">
            <xp:viewColumnHeader value="Form" id="viewColumnHeader3" iconSrc="#{javascript:getViewSortIcon(this)}">
            <xp:this.attrs>
                    <xp:attr name="onclick">
                        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:getViewSortLink(this)}]]></xp:this.value>
                    </xp:attr>
                </xp:this.attrs>
            </xp:viewColumnHeader>
        </xp:viewColumn>
    </xp:viewPanel>

</xp:view>
```

The view used has a sortable column named "Form", sortable in both directions.

And here is the SSJS library, unoptimized and undocumented:

```
/**
 * returns a link for sorting a view panel
 * 
 * @author Sven Hasselbach
 * @version 0.1
 */
function getViewSortLink( colHeader:com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspViewColumnHeader ){

    var col:com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspViewColumn = colHeader.getParent();
    var vp:com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspViewPanel = col.getParent();
    var ds:com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoViewData = vp.getDataSource();
    var curSortOrder = vp.getDataSource().getSortOrder();

    var sortCol = context.getUrlParameter("sortColumn");
    var sortOrder = context.getUrlParameter("sortOrder");

    if( sortCol === col.getColumnName() ){
        if( curSortOrder === null || curSortOrder === "" )
            sortOrder = "ascending";

        if( curSortOrder === "ascending" )
            sortOrder = "descending";

        if( curSortOrder === "descending" )
            sortOrder = ""

    }else{
        sortOrder = "ascending";
        sortCol = col.getColumnName();
    }

    return "window.location='" + context.getUrl().getPath() + "?sortColumn=" + sortCol + "&sortOrder=" + sortOrder + "'";
}

/**
 * returns a view icon for sorting
 * 
 * @author Sven Hasselbach
 * @version 0.1
 */
function getViewSortIcon( colHeader:com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspViewColumnHeader ){

    var col:com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspViewColumn = colHeader.getParent();
    var vp:com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspViewPanel = col.getParent();
    var ds:com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoViewData = vp.getDataSource();
    var curSortOrder = vp.getDataSource().getSortOrder();

    var sortCol = context.getUrlParameter("sortColumn");

    if( sortCol !== col.getColumnName() )
        return "http://www.google.de/images/icons/product/chrome-48.png";

    if( curSortOrder === "ascending" )
        return "https://www.google.com/intl/de/images/icons/feature/alert-b42.png"

    if( curSortOrder === "descending" )
        return "https://www.google.com/intl/de/images/icons/product/calendar-42.png"    

    return "http://www.google.de/images/icons/product/chrome-48.png";

}
```

The image can be adjusted with CSS.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Sven. This is a good start to what I'm trying to do and I appreciate the effort. I had been holding out hope that someone would tell me "here's the easy way to do it" but then... that would be XPages, huh?